# Lmod bash completion for the command

Tags: bash, environment-modules, lmod

Is there a way to achieve a "secure" autocompletion for the command loaded from module? I mean, I load a binary "dothis" and I would like to run "complete -F .... dothis" in module file so users have complete setup. Sourcing a completion file is not a good practice as it cannot be unloaded. TCL modules expose "set-function" to create something that could be used but unfortunately my system supports only Lmod. I was searching for some examples but I could not get any.

Thanks